# bash "test -r" giving cd too many arguments

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following code in my ~/.bashrc :

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```

When I run `source ~/.bashrc` this line :

```
test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
```

Triggers the message :

```
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

It seems that the message is triggered when the condition `-r ~/.dircolors` is tested. Could someone tell me why this message is appearing when there is no change of directory happening ?

Comment: Run `set -x` first, then `source .bashrc` again to show a debug trace. Look for the code executed right before this error and see what it says.

Comment: That is part of the default .bashrc (well on my Mint linux it is).  Have you modified anything in that file?  What is the content of `~/.dircolors` ?  You could start with an empty .bashrc and add sections of the default file, until you find the section and the line that causes issues (maybe that is what you have done already?).

Comment: So the message is emitted specifically because I am using the ```test``` keyword. When I changed the code from ```test -r ~/.dircolors``` to ```[ -r ~/.dircolors ]``` the message went away and came back when I used ```test```. It is not possible for me to change the functioning of ```test```, right ? It is a shell builtin.